# Regular Expressions Code Question

Tags: php, regex

I have some php code that contains regular expressions and I was wondering what does the regular expressions code do?

Here is my regex.

```
$reg = '#[^-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]#';
```

Comment: @sjngm, @birryree, and @Cybernate the `#` chars are [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) ***NOT*** being used as part of the match (unless a delimiter is added later).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression contained uses the `#` sign as delimiters (to tell where the regular expression begins and ends). The `[]` signifies that it needs to match a character with criteria as defined by the contents.

```
^-a-zA-Z0-9_
```

says: **not** "-" (hyphen), nor, chars a-z, nor chars A-Z, nor numbers 0-9, nor the underscore char, nor the space char

I've noticed that the other answers believe it's going to match the # sign, but that is ***NOT*** the case.

Edit to add: I forgot to metion it doesn't match the space char either. It's probably checking for blacklisted chars.

Answer (score 0):

It matches all the characters except alphabets, numeric, undercore(_), and - characters which are between two hash(#) signs.